# Cauchy problem for $xy'+y=y^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

What did I do wrong? I have to solve Cauchy problem.

I have:

$$xy'+y=y^2; \quad y(1) = 0.5$$

What I did:

$$\begin{align*}
x\frac{dy}{dx} &= y^2-y \\
xdy &= y^2-ydx \\
\int \frac{dy}{y^2-y} &= \int \frac{dx}{x} \\ \tag{1}
\end{align*}$$

solving separately:

$$\int\frac{dx}{x} = \ln|x| +C \tag{1a}$$

$$\int\frac{dy}{y^2-y} = \int\frac{dy}{y(y-1)} = \frac{A}{y} + \frac{B}{y-1}\tag{1b}$$

therefore:

$$\begin{cases} A =-1 \\ B =1 \end{cases}$$

and:

$$\int\frac{dy}{y} -\int\frac{dy}{y-1} = \ln|y| -\ln|y-1|+C \Leftrightarrow \ln\left|\frac{y}{y-1}\right| + C$$

And finally:

$$\begin{cases}\ln\left|\frac{y}{y-1}\right| = \ln|x| +C \\ x = 0 \\ y = 0 \\ y = 1 \end{cases}$$

But general solution is implicit, and I do not see the way to express $y$. How should I solve Cauchy problem then?

---

Small addition: yes, after applying expanent rule it is possible to get:

$$\left|\frac{y}{y-1}\right| = |x| + C_2$$

Where $C_2$ is just $e^C$

But still, I am confused a bit.

Comment: $A=-1$ and $B=1$, not $A=1$ and $B=-1$.

Comment: And why don't you find $C$?

Comment: $\log (1-y)-\log (y)=c+\log (x)$ and then $y=\dfrac{1}{e^c x+1}$ plugging $x=1$ you get $\dfrac{1}{2}=\dfrac{1}{e^c +1}$ and $c=0$ so the solution is $y=\dfrac{1}{1+x}$

Comment: After changing $A, B$ you also need to change the equations that follow. You should end up with $\left|\frac{y-1}{y}\right| = |x|C_2$, from which you can solve in terms of $y$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost have it.

After correcting $A,B$ to $A=1$ and $B=-1$ you get: 
$$\int\frac{dy}{y-1} -\int\frac{dy}{y} = \ln|y-1| -\ln|y|+C \Leftrightarrow \ln\left|\frac{y-1}{y}\right| + C$$

Then exponentiating:
$$\left|\frac{y-1}{y}\right| = |x|C_2 \Longrightarrow$$
$$\left|1-\frac{1}{y}\right| = |x|C_2 \Longrightarrow$$
$$\left|\frac{1}{1-C_2x}\right| = |y|$$

From there you can verify that: $$y=\frac1{1-C_2x}$$ solves the original equation.

Comment: originally it should have been like this:

$$-\int\frac{dy}{y} +\int\frac{dy}{y-1} = -\ln|y| +\ln|y-1|+C$$

but it seems I confused the sign somewhere, do not catch it in mind yet

Answer (score 1):

It can be solved for y explicitly in this case. I don't have my computer on me so typesetting is tough but it goes like this: exponentiate both sides, raise both sides to the -1 power, and break up the fraction. Then you get something that is easy to solve for y.